# Tail lights dont light up

Tags: lights, tail-lights

On my 2010 ford fusion i noticed my tail lights dont turn on, but my brake lights, signal lights work and hazards work. I already changed the light bulbs also.

Answer (score 1):

Are your headlights actually on when you test check your rear lights? I know that may sound crazy but there are lot of people who drive at night using the daylight running lights. If you see a little light on your instrument cluster then your headlights are on. The tail lights only will light when the park or headlights are on. The tail lights are off when the daylight running lights are on.

Answer (score 0):

check your fuses.  Does your high-beam indicator work?  It MAY be fuse 22 in-cabin.  I looked in a 2012 manual and it may not match.